# UIScrollView won't scroll when re-entering view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, ios6

I have a `UIView` (inside a View Controller, of course), and inside this `UIView`, I have a `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` contains some images and buttons. One of the buttons uses the modal Action Segue and opens up a `UIView` with a `MapView` inside, and a "back" button at the bottom that takes you back to the previous `UIView`. But upon going "back" (from the `MapView` to the `UIView`), the `UIScrollView` **does not scroll anymore** like it did before going to the MapView and back. It's like it's locked in its top position. I feel like it has something to do with delegates? I dunno though, I'm not too clear on those yet. Anyway, any insight to my scrolling issue??  Thanks!!

**Here's my .h file (where my scroll view is):**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *findUsView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *findUsScrollView;
- (IBAction)callButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)getDirButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Here's my .m file (where my scroll view is):**

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation ThirdViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBackgroundColor.png"]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.findUsScrollView];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    //this line creates the frame of the scrollview (dimensions)
    [self.findUsScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 750)];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //dimensions of content within scrollveiw. Scrolling enabaled.
    [self.findUsScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.findUsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 751)];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)callButton:(id)sender {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0000000000"]];
}

- (IBAction)getDirButton:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

**Here's the .h file for the Map View:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *titleBarMap;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *bottomNavBarMap;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topTitlesOverlay;
- (IBAction)backButtonMap:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Here's the .m file for the Map View:**

```
#import "MyMapViewController.h"

@implementation BountMapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)backButtonMap:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^(void){
    ThirdViewController *vc = (ThirdViewController *)[self presentingViewController];
    [[vc findUsScrollView] becomeFirstResponder];

}];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `[self.findUsScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 172, 320, 680)];` and `[self.findUsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 680)];` to viewDidLoad as a first suggestion. You don't want those to be called everytime your view appears.

Second, your contentSize and frameSize are the same (320, 680). This means your UIScrollView does not need to scroll. Remember: for a UIScrollView to scroll it's content size must be **bigger** than it's frame size. That should be all, and of course: `setScrollEnabled: YES;`

Comment: Well, turns out, if I don't have `[self.findUsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 680)];` in viewDidAppear, then it doesn't scroll at all.  I just now commented out my entire viewDidAppear, and it didn't affect anything, so apparently I didn't need it at all in the first place.  Any other ideas?  I've searched and searched. Oh, and how is it that I didn't need to use setFrame?? It's commented-out now, and nothing was affected.

Comment: If you set the scrollview in Interface Builder, you don't need the setFrame, it will be already set by the time viewWillAppear is called. If your scrollView frame size is (320, 680), your contenSize for that scrollView must be bigger, let's say 320, 750) if you want it to scroll vertically. Try doing some NSLogs for the scrollView's frame size and content size in viewWillAppear. Keep in mind: If you want your scrollView to scroll, it's content size must be bigger than it's frame size.

Answer (score 0):

Your override of `viewDidAppear` is calling `[super viewWillAppear:]` instead of `[super viewDidAppear:]`

Comment: Ah, good catch, I'll fix that when I get to work on Monday. But is that just an error you noticed? Or do you think that's what's causing the problem?